# Multiple sounds at the same time with MediaPlayer

Tags: java, android, audio, media-player

How can I get, say max 10 sounds playing at the same time?
I searched and found SoundPool, but it's not an option - because my sounds are bigger than 1Mb.

I tought making one instance of MediaPlayer for each sound, but I don't know if it works.

I know I may need the MediaPlayer, but I read issues in other questions, like too many instances of this object, and now I don't know how to manage that.

Is there any library to work with multiple sounds, or what's the proper way to do that with MediaPlayer?

Comment: You could look at AudioTrack class in android.

Comment: Im checking it, but it looks like ... if you need to change the sounds in real time etc...
I tried making max 10 mediaplayer instances and it looks good, no issues, and low cpu usage, so im going to try with it. ;)